# Selecting all columns that have some specific values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with more than 50 columns and 10,000 rows I want select those columns that are haveing 0 or 1 in them excluding other values in those columna

sample  data.frame is as below:

```
dummy_df <- data.frame(
                        id=1:4,
                        gender=c(4,1,0,1),
                        height=seq(150, 180,by = 10),
                        smoking=c(3,0,1,0)
                       )
```

I want to select all those columns with 0 or 1 value  and exclude other values like 4 in gender and 3 in smoking and as below

```
  gender  smoking
    1         0
    0         1
    1         0
```

but I have 50 columns in actual data frame and I don't know which of them are having 0 or 1

**What I'm trying is:**

```
 dummy_df %>% select_if(~ all(  . %in% 0:1))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Your code is correctly returning an empty dataset because none of the columns in the example dataset contain only values of 0 or 1.

Comment: @Lief Esbenshade I am trying to select all those columns that are having values as 0 or 1 and exclude values other than 0 or 1 in those columns like gender and smoking have values as 4 and 3 which should be excluded I want only 0 or 1 in those columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this useful for you?

```
dummy_df %>% 
  select(- c(id, height)) %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across() == 0)|any(c_across() == 1))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Rowwise: 
  gender smoking
   <dbl>   <dbl>
1      1       0
2      0       1
3      1       0
```

**EDIT**:

If you don't know in advance which cols contain `0` and/or `1`, you can determine that in `base R`:

```
temp <- dummy_df[sapply(dummy_df, function(x) any(x == 0|x == 1))]
```

Now you can filter for rows with `0`and/or `1`:

```
temp %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(c_across() == 0)|any(c_across() == 1))
```

Comment: Thank you but in this case you select everything but id and height my question is I have 50 columns that I dont which of them are having 0 or 1 otherwise I would have filter it   ``` dummy_df %>% filter (gender %in% 0:1, smoking %in% 0:1)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's more like a case of `filter` than `select`:

```
library(dplyr)


dummy_df %>%
  filter(if_all(c(gender, smoking), ~ .x %in% c(0, 1)))


  id gender height smoking
1  2      1    160       0
2  3      0    170       1
3  4      1    180       0
```